# Geocoding a table of addresses: reading a Fiona collection to a Python dictionary is taking a lot of time

Tags: python, geocoding, fiona

I read a points shapefile into a Fiona collection. The shapefile includes 9.2 millions of points. The points include textual addresses and postcodes. I have another table with around 5000 thousand addresses. I want to join the coordinates of the points to this table.

I am trying to read the Fiona collection into a Python dictionary, excluding some of the records if they do not fulfill a condition. My processor runs at 3.2Ghz and I have 16Gb of RAM. The reading has took more than an hour. I guess the resulting dictionary will be too big to be useful. Following my approach:

```
import fiona
import numpy

fiona_collection = fiona.open('addresses_points.shp') #the points file has a lot of addresses, most of them are not interesting for me.
mycity_addresses = {}
mycity_postcodes = xrange(1000, 20001) #series of postcodes I do want to read
for i in fiona_collection:
    rec = fiona_collection.next()
    if int(rec['properties']['Postcode'][:4]) in mycity_postcodes:
        mycity_addresses[rec['id']] = rec
```

Overall, what I want is to geocode the table of addresses with the respective coordinates. What would be an easy way to do this?

Comment: I don't know much about this, but it sounds like you're trying to join large amounts of data in a reasonable amount of time.  SQL is made for that use case - why not put the data in a SQL database and do the work there?

Comment: Sounds good! Can I do that in Python? How can I store the coordinates and the extra information fields in a SQL? Is there a straightforward way to do it without expending too much time on configuring a SQL server?

Comment: Python comes with [SQLite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) built in, although it's not as performant as a SQL server you'd set up, since the database is stored as a single file on the hard drive.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just had a look in SQLite. I would like to further ask another question. Can I store Python objects in the SQLite tables, by dumping the former as JSON objects, for instance?.

Comment: I fixed the loop over the fiona collection. This is working now. Setting the output dictionary takes a lot of time though. I tried to write each fiona record to a SQLite table, but I started having encoding errors. I am running in a Windows 7 machine, which terminal es encoded in ASCII, so common strings in Western, non-English languages, can not be handled. I read a bit about changing the encoding of the Windows terminal to UTF-8. But it seems it is not advisable. I also tried to .encode('utf-8') each of the elements of the row to be written to the SQLite table without good results. Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any advice.  I hope you can find a solution to these issues.